# Swift - FireStore/FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've incorporated Firebase Cloud Messaging into my app. After messing around, I kind of understood the premise of how it operates. So, as a result, I structured my code so that when users sign up the FCM token is stored. After creating two accounts, I realise both FCM tokens for the user were the same.

Looked online and sorted this issue, and now I can refresh the token on launch, and still append the new FCM token when users initially sign up.

So now, I ask the question - Users are created with a fcmToken field (which I can refer to in my code), however, due to the fact a new token is generated on launch each time does this render the token(s) stored for each user useless? Or can I still push to the specific user using the fcmToken?

I've looked online, but can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

FCM tokens don't uniquely identify an individual end user.  They identify a specific installation of an app on a specific device.  When sending with that token, it doesn't matter who is signed in to the app (or if anyone is signed in at all) - the app will still receive it and need to figure out what to do with it.  It's up to you to decide what to do with that message, given the sign-in state of the user.  If you expect that your app could have multiple users sharing a single app on a single device, then you will probably want to send something in the payload to determine who that message was intended for, if necessary.

Comment: As stated above "they identify a specific installation of an app on a specific device".  Not all apps are going to share the same token.  That would be insanity otherwise. But for your one app, it's going to be unique per device, and possibly change over time.

Comment: Ah, yes I've read up on it. With the way in which my app is structured, it's only one account per device, in theory. Sure you can log out and create a new account. What is the best case scenario to to refresh a token, if I need to, that is?

Comment: That will happen for you.  You'll need to follow the instructions to make sure your app receives updates if and when they happen.

Answer (score 0):

@doug great answer, but there's a common implementation problem when people share a device, so please add a warning, something like: often only the last logged in user should receive push notifications, otherwise he could see messages from the person who was logged in before. your backend should not only store all the devices a user is logged in, but also for each device who the last active user is and check this upon sending a push. the question whether you receive push or not when logged out is a common topic, too.